# MVC3 getting random values from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way to get values randomly from model ?

```
public string Oku()
        {

            var query = (from b in db.banner orderby Guid.NewGuid() select new { b.banner_image_name }).Take(1);



            return ("<img src='/banner_image/" + query.FirstOrDefault().banner_image_name.ToString() + "' width='154px' height='108px'/>");


        }
```

Comment: What random value ? Where you want to use it ?

Comment: ok, from what all I could understand of the code, I think you are fetching a number from db, and using the number you are preparing an image fileName which you want to display in the view. I can be totally wrong, pls correct me if dats the case.

Answer (score 1):

Get the items, Create a random number between 0 and the Total number of Banners, Get that banner from the List of banners

```
public string SomeImage()
{    
   var banners=db.banner.ToList();
   int totalBanners=banners.Count();
   Random rand=new Random();
   int randomNumb=rand.Next(0, totalBanners);
   var randomBanner=banners[randomNumb];
   return ("<img src='/banner_image/"+randomBanner..banner_image_name+"' />");
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but i got this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index" at var randomBanner=banners[randomNumb]